# how to check the length of the php array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two div 1st div contains some value and second div has the
 php array which is fetching from the backend. i want to check on page load that if the array is empty or it contains some value using the javascript. if it contains the value i should minimize the 1st div else it should expand.
code:

```
<div class="firstdiv ">
  <div >
    <p class="jb_text"><?php echo $per->name;?></p><hr>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="seconddiv ">
    <div class="panel-group" >
      <?php if($data): ?>
        <?php foreach($data as $work): ?>
          <div class="panel panel-default" id = "transp">
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 cd-name text-capitalize"><?php echo $work->first_name." ".$work->last_name; ?>
           </div>   
          </div> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to check the length of the php array in javascript.

Comment: PHP and JavaScript are different languages, you can use one in the other, but not access it's data - if you want to check the size of the array onload you'll have to recreate in JavaScript using PHP to check the size then

Comment: Why in JavaScript specifically? It can be done using PHP based on your current setup.

Comment: @ Script47 because for minimizing the div i should check whether it contains value or not

Comment: @Sam Swift 웃 can u tell me how to do

Comment: @lakshmipriya, in your PHP, you can replace `if(data)` with `if(count(data))` and if not there, it won't show. You could also just wrap all in `if (count($data))` and again if there is no data, it won't be on screen

Comment: @lakshmipriya have u worked before with php and javascript ?

Comment: It'll be worth if you make use of bootstrap accordions & play well with PHP if-else blocks. Here's the ref. for accordions - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h

Answer (score 1):

You can't "count the php array with javascript". Php is server side, javascript is client side.
That being said, you can count the displayed element by the php `foreach`.

To do so, with Jquery you can go with :

```
if(!$('.panel panel-default').length) {
    $('.seconddiv').hide();
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to be more complete, but if you don't know how to use that code, I suggest you read further documentation on how to use javascript, there's plently of good tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

in browser you need to count the `div` or element by `class` in this case

```
<script>
seconddivLength = document.querySelectorAll(".panel.panel-default").length;
alert("seconddiv Length is: " + seconddivLength)
</script>
```

Comment: it is not printing any value

Comment: its not printing value but showing you dialog in browser, updated the answer, try adding `<script>..</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't count a PHP array with Javascript.

Try something like this though.

```
   <div class="firstdiv ">
      <div >
        <p class="jb_text"><?php echo $per->name;?></p><hr>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="seconddiv ">
        <div class="panel-group" >
          <?php if(isset($data) && is_array($data) && count($data) >= 1): ?>
            <?php foreach($data as $work): ?>
              <div class="panel panel-default" id = "transp">
               <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 cd-name text- 
   capitalize"><?php echo $work->first_name." ".$work->last_name; ?>
               </div>   
              </div> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          <?php else: ?>
            <!-- What ever else you want if its empty -->
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```